# netlify gatsby - markdownRemark on a list widget

Tags: graphql, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

I've added a new page to the `config.yml` file from the [gatsby netlify started repo](https://github.com/netlify-templates/gatsby-starter-netlify-cms/blob/master/static/admin/config.yml):

```
  - name: "pages"
    label: "Pages"
    files:
      - file: "src/pages/CV/index.md"
        label: "CV"
        name: "CV"
        fields:
          - {
              label: "Template Key",
              name: "templateKey",
              widget: "hidden",
              default: "cv-page",
            }
          - { label: "Name", name: "name", widget: "string" }
          - { label: "Portrait", name: "portrait", widget: "image" }
          - label: "Categories"
            name: "categories"
            widget: "list"
            fields:
              - { label: Title, name: title, widget: string }
              - { label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown" }
```

And then I query for the data in my cv-page component:

```
export const cvPageQuery = graphql`
  query CVPage($id: String!) {
    markdownRemark(id: { eq: $id }) {
      frontmatter {
        name
        portrait
        categories {
          title
          body
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

now I would like [gatsby-transformer-remark](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark/?=gatsby-transformer-remark) to parse the categories body from markdown to html - but the query is just returning a markdown string (for example `body: "* one↵* two↵* three↵* four"`).

Before when I had the markdown widget directly on the page as a field, I would just query for `html` outside of `frontmatter` and the data would be there. Why is this not working with the widget being nested in a list?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: [repo with my code](https://github.com/Shooshte/svobodneSanje) for reference

Answer (score 0):

The `gatsby-transformer-remark` transform will only transform the markdown within the body of your `.md` file. It does not know to transform fields within your `frontmatter`.

`pages/CV/index.md`

```md
---
templateKey: cv-page
name: Miha Šušteršič
portrait: /img/headshot.png
categories:
  - body: |-
      * one
      * two
      * three
      * four
    title: Work experience
  - body: |-
      * one
      * two 
      * three
      * four
    title: Education and training
---
```

From query:

```json
{
  "markdownRemark": {
    "html": "",
    "frontmatter": {
      "name": "Miha Šušteršič",
      "portrait": "/img/headshot.png",
      "categories": [{
          "title": "Work experience",
          "body": "* one\n* two\n* three\n* four"
        },
        {
          "title": "Education and training",
          "body": "* one\n* two \n* three\n* four"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see from the query results above, your html is empty because the body is empty.